# DTFT of $(-1)^{n}\frac{\sin((7\pi / 8 )n )}{\pi n}$

Tags: discrete-signals, impulse-response

The DTFT without $(-1)^{n}$ is relatively easy but with $(-1)^{n}$ I am not sure how it would be solved. I hope anyone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

1. $(-1)^n=e^{jn\pi}$. What is its DTFT?
2. Multiplication with $(-1)^n$ corresponds to convolution in the frequency domain with the DTFT you obtained in step 1.

Comment: We can express $(-1)^{n}$ in terms of two unit-impulses right?

Comment: Following from the hint above, if $y(n) = (-1)^n x(n)$ where $x(n)=\frac{\sin(7\pi/8 n)}{\pi n}$, then the DTFT $Y(\omega) = X(\omega-\pi)$